# Where should my importer go in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have written an importer that takes an Excel file and runs through specific sheets and imports the data into the app.

I want it to be able to run from a background job but I'm just wondering where I should store this importer?

Do I create a model for it or a controller?

Where is the right place to do so?

Comment: It can just be a ruby class. Most people put it either in models dir (but you don't inherit from activerecord like your other models) or create a services dir or a lib dir and put it there.

Comment: A Rake task is one possibility

Comment: Sounds like a valid use case for [ActiveJob](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html).

Comment: @Joel_Blum Ok, I've turned it into an Importer class. I have a method in there called import.   How would I actually run that?